# Como mudar um texto de um elemento de cabeçalho em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Qual é a melhor função que muda o texto de um elemento de cabeçalho (`h1`, `h2`, `h3`, etc) através do JavaScript?

Eu tentei desta maneira mudar o texto:

```
function mudarTexto(id, novoTexto){
  document.getElementById(id).innerText = novoTexto;
}
```

Mas o texto permanece o mesmo. Veja o exemplo que eu criei no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2304rpnf/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O seu código está correto e funciona. O problema é que o jsFiddle encapsula o seu JavaScript dentro de uma função onLoad e aí a sua função fica fora de escopo para o que está no html.

Mude no jsFiddle para `noWrap` e já funciona.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Versão a funcionar: http://jsfiddle.net/2304rpnf/2/

Se quiser usar isto num site então pode colocar a função no documento, onde quiser. Uma vez que está a defenir uma função somente, então não precisa de estar dentro de nenhuma outra função `onload` ou `domready`.

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/2304rpnf/3/

Se quiser insertir esse código num ficheiro à parte pode adicionar na página com

```
<script src="oMeuScript.js"></script>
```

no caso de estar na mesma diretoria que o `index.html`. Se não estiver tem que mostrar o caminho desde a root: `src="/ < caminho > /oMeuScript.js"`