# Objeto Date() não funciona no Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript

O meu código em Javascript têm um objeto Date, contudo este script só funciona no Chrome e no IE, sendo que no Firefox não aparece nada, porque isso acontece?

Código:

```js
function relogio(elemento){
   
 var target = document.querySelector(elemento);    
 var rel = new Date();
 var hora   = rel.getHours();
 var minuto   = rel.getMinutes();
 var segundo  = rel.getSeconds();
    
 if(hora < 10){
  hora = "0"+hora;
 }
 if(minuto < 10){
  minuto = "0"+minuto;
 }
 if(segundo < 10){
  segundo = "0"+segundo;
 }
 target.innerText = hora+":"+minuto+":"+segundo;
}
window.setInterval("relogio('#relogio')", 1000);
```

```html
<div id="relogio">
  
</div>
```

Também disponível no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qkssh4s1/3/).

Por favor apresentem só soluções em Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A razão para o teu código não funcionar no jsFiddle é porque essa função `relogio` está a ser declarada dentro do `onload` do jsFiddle, e por isso não disponível no escopo global em que o `eval` do `setInterval` corre. Há outra pergunta com um problema parecido aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/35268/129

Corrigindo isso fiacaria assim: https://jsfiddle.net/qkssh4s1/5/

Sugestão de melhoramanto:

```
function relogio(id) {
    var target = document.querySelector(id);
    function pad(nr) {
        return nr < 10 ? '0' + nr : nr;
    }
    return function() {
        var rel = new Date();
        var hora = rel.getHours();
        var minuto = rel.getMinutes();
        var segundo = rel.getSeconds();
        target.innerText = [hora, minuto, segundo].map(pad).join(':');
    }
}
window.setInterval(relogio('#relogio'), 1000);
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qkssh4s1/4/