# Function nao roda 2x

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma function `selectStep()` que recebe um `onclick` por parâmetro `1` ou `2`, ela roda o que foi passado. O impasse é que tenho duas divs `Content1` e `Content2`, ambas com a mesma coisa. Porém só roda a primeira, a segunda não repete.

Sou iniciante, desde já agradeço qualquer tipo de ajuda, crítica.
Obrigado!

[SOURCE](https://jsfiddle.net/m2uogLf7/)

Answer (score 1):

Quando tenho esse tipo de situação, eu prefiro usar um atributo data para definir o elemento alvo, como no exemplo abaixo:

```js
$('[data-target]').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.content').hide();
  $($(this).data('target')).show();
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content" id="content1">Lorem Ipsum 1</div>
<div class="content" id="content2">Lorem Ipsum 2</div>
<a href="#" data-target="#content1">1</a>
<a href="#" data-target="#content2">2</a>
<a href="#" data-target=".content">Todos</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

O teu código está correto e funciona com pequenos ajustes no jsFiddle.

- não uses o `onLoad` do jsFiddle, ele coloca o teu código dentro de uma função e as funcões que tinhas deixam de ser globais e o HTML deixa de as encontrar. O mesmo problema [que esta outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/35268/129).
- adiciona o jQuery no jsFiddle, o teu código precisa de carregar a biblioteca

A funcionar: https://jsfiddle.net/m2uogLf7/2/